# How to deploy Apple's Object Capture API in the cloud

Tags: swift, amazon-ec2, arkit, photogrammetry

The Apple Object Capture API is currently only available as a MacOS API. I'm looking to host this API in the cloud so it is accessible as a REST API. This way, I can send images from an app to our cloud database (Firebase Firestore) and process the images with the Object Capture API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no web Object Capture service (or REST API).

You will need to implement your own wrapper around it (to store images, process them and expose the results)